# How to override `toString()` properly to get rid of hash code

Tags: java, android, tostring, android-room

I'm retrieving test data from `Room`, but all I get is the hash-code data, even though I override the `toString()` method in my `@Entity` class. How do I know if the override method is used at all?

I have properly set up `Room` with a `database`, `repository`, `viewModel` and `view` using `Live-data`. From onCreate I have an `observer` that triggers correctly, and data is shown. As expected it is `has-code` data. Usually I turn this into `string` data by overriding `toString()` in the `@Entity` class and then using it in `onCreate()` but it doesn't work. It still gives me the `hash` data.

In my `@Entity` class I override `toString()` like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MyEntity{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", title='" + title + '\'' +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", priority=" + priority +
            '}';
}
```

And in my `onCreate()` I call the `Interface` using:

```
myViewModel.getAllData().observe( this, new Observer<List<MyEntity>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MyEntity> myEntities) {

            Log.d("TAG: ", "DATA CHANGED! " + myViewModel.getAllData().toString());
        }
} );
```

But despite using `.toString()` I still just get the hash data:

```
D/TAG:: DATA CHANGED! android.arch.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$1@a12e85e
```

I expect some basic test data:

```
"MY FIRST OBJECT", "THIS IS MY OBJECT", 1
```

Comment: Which class is that `toString` method in?  Is it the first inner class of `ComputableLiveData`?

Comment: you call toString on List instance

Comment: @wardziniak That doesn't matter.  It's clear that whatever implementation of `List` this is, it uses a `toString` that iterates through the elements, calling `toString` on each.

Comment: @Dawood It's in my Entity class where the annotated variables for Room are found.  I have placed it there in previous projects and it has worked fine. ComputableLiveData is not a class I have created. I honestly have no idea what that is... Let me know if I should provide more of my code.

Comment: @wardziniak, @Dawood, Yes, using `toString()` on a list shouldn't pose a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `toString()` on `ComputableLiveData`,
you have to call `toString()` on `myEntities` which will in turn call `toString()` on the individual elements which are `MyEntity`.

```
myViewModel.getAllData().observe( this, new Observer<List<MyEntity>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MyEntity> myEntities) {
        Log.d("TAG: ", "DATA CHANGED! " + myEntities.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah, I see! I can't actually access the data from the `Live-data`. It seems obvious now that I look at the parameter in the `onChanged` method: `@Nullable List<MyEntity> myEntities`. Of course that is what I should use! Thanks a lot for clearing things up @Willi. And thank you for taking the time! :)